# How to save uint8array media files on nodejs server received from frontend web streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, nodejs-stream

I have used the web streams on the frontend side to send big files into multiple chunks , but when it comes to the backend nodejs side i am not able to consume the received unit8array properly . all i got is unsupported file format while saving it to disk.

Here is my code :

```
import { Writable, Readable } from "stream";
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { pipeline } from "stream/promises";

const headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Method": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
};

createServer(async (request, response) => {

  if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
    response.writeHead(204, headers);
    response.end();
    return;
  }

  response.writeHead(200, headers);

  async function* consumeStream() {
    let body = Readable.toWeb(request).getReader();
    let read = (await body.read()).value;
    // received read as an uint8array
    yield Buffer.from(read, "base64");
  }

  await pipeline(
    consumeStream,
    new Writable({
      write(chunk, enc, cb) {
        writeFileSync("./output.jpg", chunk);
        cb();
      },
    })
  );

}).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```